# How to get the response status value of system command execution in PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell

I want to know the response status of system command execution in PHP, I tried this below code , but it always returns 0 value ,Here is my code:

```
<?php
system("ls -lrt ",$return_value);
echo $return_value;
?>
```

Comment: `0` exit code in *nix world means everything went well. Why would you expect it to vary for a simple `ls`?

Comment: sample command I have taken is 'ls' , but complex command I am using in my code like 'lpr' CUPS command , so I need to know printer command is  successfully executed or not ?

Comment: I don't know about lpr specifically, but what you might consider unsuccesful doesn't have to be a reason for non-0 exit status for the program.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will consider that non 0 value as unsuccessful execution of command

Answer (score 0):

In bash，it uses 0 to express everything is ok. The command 'ls -lrt' will not fail, so it return 0. If you want to get output, you should use exec()

Comment: If command is wrong also it will return '0', so it is not proper response status of command

Comment: In my system(centos, PHP5.6.3),I exec command: system('unlink xxx', $res), and the command is wrong. It will return 1.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried this, system command is wrong it will return 127 response status